# BindValue in a sql statement between quotes

Tags: php, pdo

Im trying to execute something like this

```
$SQL = "INSERT into cb_sent_alerts(user_id,message) 
    Select id, ' :message ' from story1";


$stmt->bindValue(':message', $_POST['message']);
```

But that just sends :message to the database, not the values of $_POST['message']; What can i do?

EDIT: very sorry should have specified, :message is not a column in cb_sent_alerts, rather i want the message there as a string.

Comment: Have you read the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) documentation?

Comment: if you remove the quotes then it tries to read the contents as a column, where i want to use it as a string. I have but im admit im not the best at reading that sort of documentation.

Comment: So the first person who posted was right, i thought it would take it as a column, but instead it just worked as a string. So id give the first person some points, but he/she removed his comment.

Comment: You cannot give points for comments. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it's never mentioned in the doc explicitly, you can work with placeholders in `SELECT` part of `INSERT ... SELECT` query the same way as with any other type of query. So this:

```
INSERT INTO cb_sent_alerts(user_id,message) 
    SELECT id, :message FROM story1
```

... end up with the right value (a string) if bound up by `bindValue(':message', $_POST('message')` call.

Note that placeholders cannot be used for the column and table names, so the thing you were afraid of is just not possible. )